# How to create delegate instance?

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

i have a function

```
void __stdcall TestThread( String^ a, String^ b)
{
 MessageBox::Show( a );
 MessageBox::Show( b );

 _endthread();
}
```

And i want to create a thread like this:
`_beginthread( &HWSW_GUI::Form1::TestThread , 0, NULL );`

Unfortunately i'm getting an error:
`Error  2   error C3374: can't take address of 'HWSW_GUI::Form1::TestThread' unless creating delegate instance  d:\testvs2008\hwsw_gui\hwsw_gui\Form1.h 5177`

Can someone help me please? It is driving me crazy, and i can't it figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix managed and unmanaged code. Instead of _beginthread use managed thread http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx#Y5314

Comment: @AlexFarber: Thanks! It is working now. One more question. How can i pass arguments to the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use managed thread instead of _beginthread.

To pass parameter to the thread, use Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart) constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx

Generally, working with any .NET language, including C++/CLI, avoid using unmanaged stuff (like PInvoke or mixing managed/unmanaged code in C++/CLI), unless this is absolutely necessary. Most standard programming tasks may be solved using pure managed code.

Comment: And do you know how to pass multiple arguments to a thread? For example a bool, and a String^? That's why i wanted to use _beginthread because i couldn't get it work :( I couldn't pass multiple arguments this way

Comment: Create class which contains everything you need, and pass this class instance as thread parameter.